# Обработчик входящих сообщений WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket

Дано:

1. Сервер Websocket с неким количеством каналов N, с которых можно
   получать сообщения;
2. клиент, написанный на Java.

Задача:

1. Подключиться к серверу;
2. подписаться на канал для получения
   сообщения;
3. научить программу правильно обрабатывать входящие
   сообщения от сервера.

Вроде бы ничего сложного, я реализовал 2 первых пункта, код ниже. Вопрос в пункте 3. Не могу понять для чего и зачем нужен MessageHandler (библиотека javax.websocket.). При подписи на определенный канал, сообщения приходят, но не более 10-12 минут, потом соединение закрывается с ошибкой 1006(Close Reason), как только вешаю хендлер, сообщения идут нормально, но я не могу понять как эта магия работает. Создаю свой внутренний интерфейс, метод по добавлению обработчика сообщений и тут же его реализацию (посредством анонимных классов). Иииииии.... все работает. У меня конфуз, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

P.S. Предложения по использованию друх библиотек и способов реализации я учту, но интересен именно этот случай, т.к. жизненно важно понимать как эта штука работает.

Собссно код

основной класс (с точкой входа)

```
public class WSClient {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {             
            final WebSocketClientHelper clientEndPoint = new WebSocketClientHelper(new URI("wss://wsn.example.com/wsn/"));
            clientEndPoint.start(clientEndPoint);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Код реализации websocket клиента (рабочий)

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebSocketClientHelper {

    protected ConverterTo InputDataHandler = new ConverterTo();
    public ConverterTo getInputDataHandler() {
        return InputDataHandler;
    }

    protected Session userSession  = null;
    public Session getUserSession() {
        return userSession;
    }

    private MessageHandler messageHandler = null;

    public WebSocketClientHelper(URI endpointURI) {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Основные аннтотированные методы по работе с сервером

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    System.out.println("opening websocket");
    this.userSession = session;        
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    this.messageHandler.OnMessage(InputDataHandler.ConvertToJSON(message));       

}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
    System.out.println("closing websocket");
    this.userSession = null;
}

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
    }

    public void start(WebSocketClientHelper client) throws InterruptedException {
        client.sendMessage("channel"); //подписываемся на канал

        client.addMessageHandler(new WebSocketClientHelper.MessageHandler(){
            public void OnMessage(String message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }); // Вешаю хендлер и прописываю его реализацию
        Thread.sleep(1200000); //Время задано для тестирования 
    }
```

Добавление обработчика сообщений

```
private void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
    }
```

Интерфейс

```
private interface MessageHandler{
        void OnMessage(String message);
    }

}
```

Comment: посмотри http://java-websocket.org/ оченьпросто и клиентская и серверная части для любого применения

Comment: @Вадим, я обязательно посмотрю, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я не разобрался, зачем нежен хендлер(Вернее разобрался, но только на уровне теории), но проблему с закрытием сокета решил. Т.к. сообщений я обратно не отсылал, сервер попросту закрывал сокет. Достаточно создать ссылочную переменную типа RemoteEndpoint и записать туда userSession.getBasicRemote(). Затем используя метод sendPong отправлять сообщения серверу о том, что вы живы и слушаете сообщения от сервера.
Пример реализации

```
RemoteEndpoint remote = userSession.getBasicRemote();
remote.sendPong(ByteBuffer.wrap("I'm here".getBytes()));
```

Пока что все. Если таки разберусь как использовать и где этот треклятый хендлер - обязательно отпишу.